Inquiry about using a CNN and MCTS for a certain game
I'm theorizing an idea to use a CNN and MCTS together to play a certain game. In vague terms, the game has the following properties:

There are two players, and it is roughly turn-based.
Every move, there are quite a lot of choices to pick from and a lot of them aren't good.
This is a puzzle game. Each player can choose to build their board or remove certain sections of their board in a tactical way to send an "attack" to the other player, which accumulates unwanted material on their board.
Most players can judge whether a certain board is "good" or not, which means the CNN can be used as an evaluation function to judge how good a board is or not.
There is a type of attack where, if you do it n times in a row, the moment you switch to another type of attack, you will send n units of unwanted material to their board.

For beginners, it's usually very hard to do that certain attack many times, and most of the time it's more rewarding to build your board and do other attacks. Nevertheless, good players usually know techniques to build their board to maximize the amount of times where they use that attack.
What I'm worried about is when I use a CNN and MCTS on this, the program won't be able to figure out that accumulating this attack many times can have a huge reward if they build their board correctly. This is because seeing the future rewards for this attack usually goes 50-200 actions deep, and I think MCTS won't be able to explore this deep.
Is there another technique I should use?
